# Visual Studio Code: gdb: cannot access memory at adress

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-code, debugging, gdb

I cannot debug the C++ shared library with gdb via VSCode. All my breakpoints are inactive. When hovering over them, it says "cannot read memory at address ...". The symbols of the library are loaded though.
Still I can debug my library with gdb running in console. I can successfully set breakpoints, the program pauses on them, as expected.

I make the library with makefile. The compile string is as follows:

```
/opt1/gcc/bin/g++ -c -DPTR_RESTRICT= -shared -fPIC -O0 -g -DOURDEBUG1 -ggdb api.cpp -o api.o
/opt1/gcc/bin/g++ -c -DPTR_RESTRICT= -shared -fPIC -O0 -g -DOURDEBUG1 -ggdb dllmain.cpp -o dllmain.o
```

The link string is as follows:

```
/opt1/gcc/bin/g++ api.o dllmain.o .-L/opt1/gcc/bin/lib64 -nodefaultlibs -O0 -g -DOURDEBUG1 -ggdb -shared -fPIC -ldl -o mydll.so
```

I tried to create launch targets in VSCode by two ways.

First of all I just opened "launch.json" and clicked on the button "Add Configuration". Then I selected "C/C++: (gdb) Attach". VSCode created the following  code:

```
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Attach",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "attach",
            "program": "/home/adminl/Project/mylib.so",
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
```

Also I tried to create configuration by myself:

```
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Attach 2",
            "processId": "9814",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "program": "/home/adminl/Project/mylib.so",
            "request": "attach"
        }
```

But with no success. What could be the problem?

Comment: A shared library is (usually) not a program and cannot be ran or debugged by itself. You need an executable that links to this library. How do you run gdb from the console?

Comment: Yes, you are right, library is not a program. Actually I run a program, which loads the library via "dlopen" function.

I run gdb from the console simply by the command 
`gdb -p pId`, where pId is the id of the process, which loads my library.

Comment: From the MS [guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference): "program (required)
Specifies the full path to the executable the debugger will launch or attach to." Not your .so file but an actual executable of the process you are attaching to. Once you attach, and the process dlopens your shared library, you should see your breakpoints activated.

Comment: Wow, that worked, thank you!

But why should I even define the program, which I attach to? I mean, when I run gdb in console. I just specify the process id. If I run gdb in vscode, I also have to select process id. Is there a way not to specify the program?

Comment: The executable can be determined from the process ID, so in principle this field could be made optional. I don't know why exactly VSC requires it..